# Структурированные запросы

Tags: elasticsearch

У меня есть документы вида:

```
[
   {"title": "my-title", "brand": "my-brand1", "attribute-1": "attr1", "attribute-2": "attr2"},
   {"title": "my-title1", "brand": "my-brand", "attribute-1": "attr1", "attribute-2": "attr"},
   {"title": "my-title2", "brand": "my-brand", "attribute-1": "attr1", "attribute-2": "attr4"},
...
]
```

Также у меня есть запросы вида:

```
{"title": "my-title-request", "brand": "my-brand1-request", "attribute-1": "attr1-request", "attribute-2": "attr2-request"}
```

Обозначу документы как `d0, d1, d2, ..., dn`. Запрос обозначу как `q`.

Для всех пар `(di, q)`, я хочу вычислить скор для всех попарных атрибутов. Т.е. посчитать скор для `title`, `brand`, `attribute-1`, `attribute2` и посчитать результирующий score для `(di, q)`, сложив все скоры вместе.

К сожалению, с помощью `multi_match` такое сделать нельзя. Потому как `multi_match` не умеет, как я понимаю, работать со структурированными запросами. Мне посоветовали посмотреть в сторону скриптов и `rescore`. Может быть вы ткнёте конкретное место, куда мне нужно посмотреть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы решить эту проблему, можно использовать обычный `match`, воспользовавшишь оператором `should`, который работает как `or`.

[Здесь есть пример](https://dzone.com/articles/23-useful-elasticsearch-example-queries), а также можно посмотреть на одну из [первых страниц](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-filter-context.html) про DSL-язык elasticsearch. Возможно, вам пригодится оператор [dis_max](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html)